# What is the use of `putw` and `getw` function in c?

Tags: c

I wanna know the use of `putw()` and `getw()` function. As I know, these are used to write and read from file as like as `putc` and `getc` but these deals with only integers. But when I use these for writing integers, it just write different symbol in file (like if I write `65` to file using `putw()`. It writes `A` in the file). Why does it take the ASCII value? I am using codeblocks 13.12. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int num;

    fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    printf("Enter any number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    putw(num, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but is it standard C?

Comment: It most certainly does *not* "writes `A` in the file" -- not *only* an `A`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, no it's not standard, `CONFORMING TO SVr4, SUSv2.  Not present in POSIX.1-2001`

Answer (score 7):

Let's read the point to point explanation of getw() and putw() functions.

- getw() and putw() are related to FILE handling.
- putw() is use to write integer data on the file (text file).
- getw() is use to read the integer data from the file.
- getw() and putw() are similar to getc() and putc(). The only difference is that getw() and putw() are especially meant for reading and writing the integer data.

---

```
int putw(integer, FILE*);
```

Return type of the function is integer.

Having two argument first "integer", telling the integer you want to write on the file and second argument "FILE*" telling the location of the file in which the data would be get written.

Now let's see an example.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("file1.txt","w");
    putw(65,fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Here putw() takes the integer number as argument (65 in this case) to write it on the file file1.txt, but if we manually open the text file we find 'A' written on the file. It means that putw() actually take integer argument but write it as character on the file.

So, it means that compiler take the argument as the ASCII code of  the particular character and write the character on the text file.

---

```
int getw(FILE*);
```

Return type is integer.

Having one argument that is FILE* that is the location of the file from which the integer data to be read.

In this below example we will read the data that we have written on the file named file1.txt in the  example above.

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int ch;

  fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");

  ch=getw(fp);
  printf("%d",ch);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

output

```
65
```

Explanation: Here we read the data we wrote to file1.txt in above program and we will get the output as 65.

So, getw() reads the character 'A' that was already written on the file file1.txt and return the ASCII code of the character 'A' that is 65.

We can also write the above program as:

```
int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");

   printf("%d",getw(fp));

  fclose(fp);
}
```

output

```
65
```

Comment: This answer is very misleading. The information herein is confusing. What kind of prototype is this: `int putw(integer, FILE*);`?

Answer (score 4):

If `num` is an `int`, then `putw(num, fp)` is equivalent to `fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp)`, except for having a different return value.  It writes an `int` to the file in binary format.  `getw` is similar but with `fread` instead.  You can see how glibc implements them: [`putw`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/putw.c;h=f3dc1e45c99ca33fe44f05afbce63c3b0e9f1a04;hb=HEAD),[`getw`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/getw.c;h=9615898a7cf8247b59f6879de71729ab5679f6f6;hb=HEAD).

This means that:

- They are not appropriate for writing text.  If you want to write a number to a file in human-readable decimal or hexadecimal format, use `fprintf` instead.
- They typically read/write more than one byte (one character) to the file.  For instance, on a machine with 32-bit `int`s, they will read/write four bytes.  Attempting to do `putw('c')` will not simply write the single character `'c'`.
- They should only be used with files opened in binary mode (if that makes a difference on your system).
- You should not expect the contents of the file to be human-readable at all.  If you attempt to view the file in an editor, you'll see the representation of whatever bytes are in the file, in your current character set (e.g. ASCII).
- You should not expect the file to be successfully read back on another computer that uses a different internal representation for `int` (e.g. different width, different endianness).

On a typical system with 32-bit little-endian `int`, `putw(65, fp)` will result in the four bytes `0x41 0x00 0x00 0x00`.  The `0x41` (decimal 65) is the ASCII code for the character `A`, so you'll see that if you view it.  The `0x00` bytes may or may not be displayed at all, depending on what you are using to view.

**These function are not a good idea to use in new code.**  Even if you do need to store binary data in files, which has various disadvantages as noted and should usually only be done if there is a very good reason for it, you should simply use `fwrite` and `fread`.  `getw`/`putw` are a worse option because:

- **They will make your code less portable.** `fwrite/fread` are part of the ISO C standard, which is the most widely supported cross-platform modern standard for the C language.  `getw/putw` were present in the Single Unix Specification v2 version 2, which dates to 1997 and is now obsolete.  They were not included in the POSIX/SUSv3 specs which superseded SUSv2, and it would be unwise to count on them being available on new systems.
- **They will make your code less readable.** Since `fread`/`fwrite` are far more widely used, another programmer reading your code will recognize immediately what they do.  Since `getw`/`putw` are more obscure, people are likely to have to go and look them up, and the names don't make it easy to remember that they operate specifically on the type `int`.  Readers may also confuse them with the similarly-named ISO-standard functions `getwc/putwc`.  So using `getw/putw` makes your code less readable.
- **They may introduce subtle bugs.** `getw` returns `EOF` on end-of-file or error, but `EOF` is a valid integer value (often `-1`).  Therefore, if it returns this value, you cannot easily tell whether the file actually contained the integer `-1`, or whether the read failed.  And since this only happens for one particular value, it may be missed in testing.  You can check `ferror()` and `feof()` to distinguish the two cases, but this is awkward, easy to forget to do, and negates most of the apparent convenience of the "simpler" interface of `getw` compared to `fread`.

I speculate that the only reason these functions existed in the first place is that, like `putc` (respectively `getc`), `putw` could be implemented as a macro that directly wrote the buffer of `fp` and would thus be a little more efficient than calling `fwrite`.  Such an implementation is no longer feasible on modern systems, since it wouldn't be thread-safe, so `putw` needs a function call anyway.  In fact, with glibc in particular, `putw` just calls `fwrite` after all, with the overhead of an *additional* function call, so it's now *less* efficient. So there is no longer any reason at all to use these functions.

Comment: So confused. Since when is it safe to write to the same stdio `FILE *` object from two threads?

Comment: @Joshua: Since C11.  See 7.21.2 (7-8) in [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  Every stream has a built-in lock, and stdio library functions acquire the lock for all I/O.

Comment: Of course, if you care which data ends up in the file in which order, you probably need to do your own locking or synchronization.  But it does mean you can do something like have all your threads `fprintf` log messages to stderr or a common log file without causing a data race (UB) or mixing up the characters of separate messages.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `putw()` and `getw()`

> getw()  reads  a  word  (that is, an int) from stream.  It's provided for compatibility with SVr4.
>
> putw() writes the word w (that is, an int) to stream.  It is provided for compatibility with SVr4.

You can use the fread and fwrite function for better use.

`getw()` reads the integer from the given FILE stream.

`putw()` it write the integer given in the first argument into the file pointer.

getw:

It will read the integer from the file. like `getchar()` doing the work. Consider the file having the content "hello". It will read the h and return ascii value of h.

putw:

It will place the given integer, integer taken as a ascii value. Corresponding value of the ascii value placed in the file. like `putchar()`

Comment: *Consider the file having the content "hello". It will read the h and return ascii value of h*: not at all. the return value will not be the ASCII value of `h`.

Answer (score 0):

### Beware!  The Linux implementation is completely different from the original AT&T definition!

What `putw` and `getw` are:

- A quick hack to write `int`s to a file, and read them back *on the same machine*.

They have many compatibility issues:

- They depend on the size of an `int`, which is not standardized.
- Implementations differ on whether they produce human-readable text, or binary.
- There is no guarantee on the byte order of what is produced.  Maybe it is the processor's endianness, maybe it is network byte order.

---

Both functions are listed in my copy of *The C Programmer's Handbook*, written by AT&T Bell Laboratories in 1984.  This is after the 1st edition of K&R, but before the first ANSI C standard and the 2nd edition of K&R.  At that point in history, even basic measures of compatibility between machines (such as `size_t`, `INT_MAX`, and `int32_t`) did not yet exist.

These functions appear on page 50 in a section titled "WORD I/O":

[image: C Programmer's Handbook page 50]

Notice that it states that `getw` accepts "characters delimited by whitespace".  This means that the AT&T implementation uses text (not binary) format.  The format (decimal, hexadecimal, etc) of the text is unclear.

---

On my Linux machine, `putw` and `getw` are clearly using *binary* file format.  My test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    putw('T', stdout);
    putw('e' + 's'*256, stdout);
    putw('t' + 'i'*256 + 'n'*65536 + 'g'*256*65536, stdout);
    printf("!\n");
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        printf("getw=%08X, ", getw(stdin));
        printf("ferror=%d\n", ferror(stdin));
    }
    printf("===Done===\n");
}
```

and its output:

```
Testing!
1234
getw=34333231, ferror=0
4321
getw=3233340A, ferror=0
getw=FFFFFFFF, ferror=0
===Done===
```

Notice that -- unlike the AT&T implementation -- it is not delimiting with whitespace (note the newline of the input appears as a 0x0A byte).  I'm willing to bet that it's merely a call to `fwrite(&w, sizeof(int), 1, stream)`.  In fact, the man page suggests using `fwrite` instead!

The man page also claims that is in Linux for compatibility with Sys V Release 4, which came out in 1988.  However, as you can see above, files produced by AT&T SVR4 will ***not*** be compatible with Linux's version of `getw`.