# Get a char on the last line of a file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

Well, I wrote a program to make some steps and when it gets a final value print on a file, using 
    `fprinf(file, "No %d | Scr %d | Secs %d\n", number, score, seconds)`, but when I run again the program and it cleaned all the stuff that was printed and made the same prints on the file, as I am using the same beginning point.
Eg.:

```
.
.
No 97 | Scr 712 | Secs 124
No 98 | Scr 5040 | Secs 342
No 99 | Scr 3621 | Secs 402
No 100 | Scr 7803 | Secs 225
```

So how can I get get the *last number* and set if for the *beginning point* and do not print before values of it as I wanted ?

Answer (score 2):

> but when I run again the program and it cleaned all the stuff that was printed and made the same prints on the file,

this occurs when you open your file in `write` mode

```
 fopen("file","w"); //write mode
```

- When you open any file in `write` mode, if file is non empty, it's made empty and file pointer is set to the beginning

---

> So how can I get the last number and set it for the beginning point and print values before of it as I wanted ?

you need not get the last number, instead open it in append mode

```
 fopen("file","a"); //append mode
```

- If you open in `append` mode , the file pointer will be automatically set to the last position in the file and the data can be appended.

---

> I need see whats the last number is before appending

**hint :**

- open the file in `read` mode and use [`fseek()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm) and [`getw()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625922/5281962) functions to get the last number.
- Now open the file in `append` mode and continue adding data into it.

> **Note :** while opening file in `read` mode, make sure the file exists if not `fopen()` returns a `NULL`, try checking for it this way :
>
> ```
> if ((fp = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) //try opening this way
> ```

---

for further reading on **files**, see here : [*click*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm)

Comment: oh now I see... But even when I am in append mode, how can I be able to just get the last number instead of the last line ?

Comment: @ViníciusGuardianoSouza there are various ways to do it.. get to know **fseek()** function and **fscanf()**, *(getting to know file functions would be really helpful)*

Comment: But the problem stills on append mode, lets say that I ran my code and the result was a very big file, eg. 300.000 lines of data, so if I do it again on the 300.001st line it will be printed with the same number of 1st, there is why I need see whats the last number is.

Comment: first open your function in read mode and get the last number using file functions... then open the file in append mode :)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm is a good point to start learning about files

Answer (score 2):

As Cherubim Anand pointed out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38284452/156811) you can resume writing to a file by opening it in append mode, but there are also functions used to mess with the read and write indicator in a file, they are `ftell()` and `fseek()`.

`ftell()` returns the absolute position you are in the file right now relative to its start (0), and `fseek()` can be used to modify this position.

`fseek()` works in 3 different modes, with absolute address (`SEEK_SET`), with an offset relative to current position (`SEEK_CUR`) or offset relative to the end of file (`SEEK_END`).

For instance, you can modify the indicator to the end of the file (same as opening in append mode)  with `fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)`.

Once the indicator is in the end of the file you can use `ftell()` to know the size of the file. Very useful.

If you want to move back to the start of the file you can use `fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)`. There is also the function `rewind()` that basically does the same thing.

If you are working with binary files containing structures you can use `fseek()` to go to specific addresses in the file to fetch information you need.