# why putw on shows correct output with getw, and fprintf and printf only shows correct output with scanf?

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

Can anyone explain me whats exactly going on here? 
I have a problem in file management.

**Explanation of code:**
Here, it takes integers from user and then stored in **DATA** file.
then it reads integers from **DATA** file and filter them by **ODD** and **EVEN** and store it respective file.

**Here is my code.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;
    int number;

    printf("Enter the content of data file\n");
    f1 = fopen("DATA","w");
    for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
    {
        /*problem is here*/
        number=getw(stdin);
        //scanf("%d",&number);

        if(number==-1 || number==EOF) break;
        putw(number,f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);


    f1 = fopen("DATA","r");
    f2 = fopen("ODD","w");
    f3 = fopen("EVEN","w");

    while((number = getw(f1))!=EOF)
    {       
        if(number % 2 == 0)
            putw(number, f3);
        else
            putw(number,f2);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);

    f2 = fopen("ODD","r");
    f3 = fopen("EVEN","r");

    printf("\n\ncontents of ODD file\n");

    while((number=getw(f2))!=EOF)
        /* problem is here */
        putw(number,stdout);        
        //fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",number);
        //printf("%d",number);

    printf("\n\ncontents of EVEN file\n");
    while((number=getw(f3))!=EOF)
        /*problem is here */
        //putw(number,stdout);
        fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",number);
        //printf("%d",number);

    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the content of data file
111
222
333
444
555


contents of ODD file
111
333
555


contents of EVEN file
171061810
171193396
```

So here, why `putw` shows correct output with `getw`, and `fprintf` and `printf` only shows correct output with `scanf`. However, data stored in all files are correct!!!

why is it so?

Comment: It's funny how `171061810` is `0xA323232`

Comment: yes I know, but why its printing address inspite of value? @KamilCuk

Comment: then how could i actually print value using printf.

Comment: Second and third clues: 171193396 is 0xA343434 and neither this nor the number mentioned in the first comment is an address.

Comment: OK, to try to be less mystical, try this code somewhere in your program: `int test = '\n222'; printf("%d\n", test);`.

Comment: @AdrianMole its print the 171061810... You are right its not address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of \`putw\` and \`getw\` function in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625696/what-is-the-use-of-putw-and-getw-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why putw shows correct output with getw, and fprintf and printf only shows correct output with scanf

Because the [getw()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getw.html) function reads the next **word** from the stream. **The size of a word is the size of an int** and may vary from machine to machine`

You can see in the comment: `171061810` is `0xA323232` (it's a hex number). When you use the ASCII code to convert from hex to character, you get:

```
Hex    Character
A  ==> \n
32 ==> 2
32 ==> 2
32 ==> 2
so
171061810 is "\n222".
```

It's similar to `444`.

Comment: could explain me how ASCII value of '\n222' converted into decimal number 171061810. just share any reference please!!

Comment: to print hex number with `printf` you can use `%x` (use `%d` for decimal). If you want to convert see the ascii code at http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Why isn't it 10505050 in decimal? \n => 10, 2 => 50, 2 => 50, 2 => 50

Comment: No, don't do it with decimal, just do it with hex number. With decimal it's more complicated (see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-method-of-converting-the-decimal-number-to-ASCII-code)

Comment: @NisheetPatel why did you uncheck the check mark ? Is there any thing not correct here ?

Comment: you are absolutely right, but i need more clarification on 10505050.... So that's why I uncheck it...

Comment: @NisheetPatel Did you read the link i gave you above. Decimal and Hex are not the same. Why do you want to apply one algorithm for two different cases ?

Comment: I just want to know How ascii convert into decimal... Do I have to ask another question for it?

Comment: Actually, its just bit confusing for me. Because i am new in it. And thanks for help..@Hitokiri

Comment: `How ascii convert into decimal`, ASCII is a sheet of code, that show you the correspondence of character with a number. You do not need to understand how ascii convert to decimal. In invert way, if you want to use the code C, use `sprintf` or `printf`. If you want the pencil and paper, see the link i gave you

Comment: the shorted comment in the link for you: That's so simple.just add 48 to each digit of the decimal no.

Eg to convert 213 into ASCII code,just add 48 to 2 then 48 to 1 and lastly 48 to three

So we get 50 49 51: 50-->2, 49==> 1, 51==>3

Comment: Yes I know that its 10505050, i was confused about 10505050 with 171061810.

Comment: remember, do not apply one algorithm to two problems.

Comment: for example, the way you calculate A+B in hex is difference in compare with A+B in decimal that is not the same with Binary

Comment: That was the actual problem