# Writing even integers up to n in a file in c, putw() function error

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm writing a program that will output all even integers up to 100 in a text file.

Here's the whole **code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;

    if ((fp = fopen("even_up_to_100.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        perror("Write");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i) {
        if (!(i % 2))
            putw(i, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if ((fp = fopen("even_up_to_100.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Read");
        exit(2);
    }
    while (!feof(fp))
        printf("%d ", getw(fp));
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT(from text file):**

```
                                     "   $   &   (   *   ,   .   0   2   4   6   8   :   <   >   @   B   D   F   H   J   L   N   P   R   T   V   X   Z   \   ^   `   b   d
```

**OUTPUT(from console window):**

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 -1
```

Please point out the error(if there's any) in the code with the solution.
Inside the text file there are some control characters, which are shown as blank spaces here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214641/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-writing-even-integers-up-to-n-in-a-file-in-c-pu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getw`/`putw` are binary I/O functions, you should be opening your file in binary mode (`"wb"` instead of `"w"` as the mode argument to `fopen`, and likewise `"rb"` instead of `"r"`).

Character 26 is ASCII Ctrl-Z, which Windows (and DOS before it) use as an end-of-file marker for text files.  So if you're on such a system, when you attempt to read the number 26 from your file, the library sees a Ctrl-Z byte and treats that as the end of the file.  That would explain why your program stops reading after 24.  Opening in binary mode disables this behavior, and will also avoid various other problems, e.g. the handling of CR characters.

Note that if your goal was, as you said, to "output all even integers up to 100 in a **text** file", then `getw`/`putw` are the wrong tools for the job as they do binary I/O, not text.  (Even if you did want binary format, you should not use `getw`/`putw` but rather `fread`/`fwrite`, as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990423/634919).)  If you want to create a text file, with human-readable contents, you should use `fprintf` and `fscanf`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I get it: you wrote [this answer to an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990423/4593267) because of the OP's comment. A much better answer than the previous leading one.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you very much for explaining why the program terminates after 24. I got your point and this helped a lot... [putw_getw@Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625696/what-is-the-use-of-putw-and-getw-function-in-c/61990423#61990423)