# Getting gibberish values in files when putw() is used

Tags: c, file-handling

Program to take integer input from user and store them in a file, then sort the integers into two different files (odd and even), when I used fprintf it overwrites the previous value thats why I tried putw() but I am getting gibberish values in files

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,a[50];
    printf("\nEnter no of entries:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    FILE *f1,*f2,*f3;
    f1=fopen("Numbers.txt","w+");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a number:");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        putw(a[i],f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    
    f1=fopen("Numbers.txt","r");
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
        {
            f2=fopen("EvenNum.txt","w+");
            putw(a[i],f2);
            fclose(f2);
        }
        else
        {
            f3=fopen("OddNum.txt","w+");
            putw(a[i],f3);
            fclose(f2);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are writing binary data not text data. So opening the file in a text editor will show "gibberish". Is that what you are doing? *when I used fprintf it overwrites the previous value*. If you want text then `fprintf` is appropriate so instead of just giving up on it try to fix it.

Comment: *it overwrites the previous value*. That's likely because you are repeatedly opening the same file in `w+` mode in the last loop. Opening in `w+` truncates the file. Instead should just open the file once before the loop.

Comment: [Don't use `putw`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990423/634919)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what `putw` does. `putw` writes an `int` in binary not as text. Do you mean `fprintf(f1, "%d", a[i]);`?

The man page for `getw` and `putw` says to use `fread` and `fwrite` instead, which doesn't seem to fit here.

`f1=fopen("Numbers.txt","w+");` will clobber the file. Do you want `"a+"` to append?