# implicit declaration of function 'putw, and a segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, implicit-declaration

The error I'm getting is:

p1.c: In function 'WriteToFile': p1.c:219:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'putw' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Not sure how to fix the problem. I'm also getting a segmentation fault. The code compiles fine, but when running the code I get the segfault. I'm assuming the error I'm getting is linked to the segmentation fault? If someone could provide some insight or propose a solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

edit: The segfault is occurring at "int k2 = atoi(argv[2]);", still don't know what's causing it though.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996).


typedef struct person_
{
    int ID;
    int mask;
    int vaccine;
    int status;
    int days_infected;
    int days_quarantined;

}Person;
#define POPULATION 500

static int vaccinated;
static int infected;
static int masked;
static int healthy;
static int oldinfected;



Person meetrandomly(FILE* IN, Person M, Person N[])
{
    //reading from the pre formatted file!!!!!!!
    float p_infected[4];
    float np = 0, hwf = 0, iwf = 0, hv = 0;
    fscanf(IN, "%*s %*s %*s %*s  %*s %*s  %*s %*s %f", &np);
    fscanf(++IN, "%*s %*s %*s %*s  %*s %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s %f", &hwf);
    fscanf(++IN, "%*s %*s %*s %*s  %*s %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s  %*s %f", &iwf);
    fscanf(++IN, "%*s %*s %*s %*s  %*s %*s  %*s  %*s %f", &hv);
    p_infected[0] = np;
    p_infected[1] = hwf;
    p_infected[2] = iwf;
    p_infected[3] = hv;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    int n = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        float* poniter1 = NULL;
        int m = rand() % POPULATION;
        Person temp = N[m];
        if (M.status == 0 && N[m].status == 0)
        {
            return M;
        }
        else if (M.status == 0 && N[m].status == 1)
        {
            if (M.mask == 0 && N[m].mask == 0)
            {

                int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
                int n = p_infected[0]*100;
                if (M.vaccine == 1)
                {
                    n = n / 10;
                }
                if (num < n)
                {
                    M.status = 2;
                    M.days_infected = 0;
                    infected++;

                }


            }
            else if (M.mask == 0 && N[m].mask == 1)
            {
                int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
                int n = p_infected[2]*100;
                if (M.vaccine == 1)
                {
                        n = n / 10;
                }
                if (num < n)
                {
                    M.status = 2;
                    M.days_infected = 0;
                    infected++;
                }

            }
            else if (M.mask == 1 && N[m].mask == 0)
            {

                int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
                int n = p_infected[1]*100;
                if (M.vaccine == 1)
                {
                    n = n / 10;
                }
                if (num <= n)
                {
                    M.status = 2;
                    M.days_infected = 0;
                    infected++;
                }
            }
            else if (M.mask == 1 && N[m].mask == 1)
            {
                int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
                int n = (hwf*iwf)*100;
                if (M.vaccine == 1)
                {
                    n = n / 100;
                }
                if (num > (100-n))
                {
                    M.status = 2;
                    M.days_infected = 0;
                    infected++;
                }

            }


        }
    }
    return M;

}
void Simulation(FILE* A, Person M[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < POPULATION; i++)
    {
        M[i] = meetrandomly(A, M[i], M);
        M++;

    }
}
Person* updation(Person B[])
{
    oldinfected = infected;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < POPULATION;i++)
    {
        if (B[i].status == 1 && B[i].days_infected < 14)
        {
            B[i].days_infected++;
        }
        else if (B[i].status == 1 && B[i].days_infected > 14)
        {
            B[i].status = 0;
            infected--;
            healthy++;
        }
        else if (B[i].status == 3 && B[i].days_quarantined > 14)
        {
            B[i].status = 0;
            infected--;
            healthy++;
        }
    }
    return B;
}
Person* Initialization(FILE* IN, Person N[], int k2, int k3, int k4, int k5, int *vaccinated, int *infected, int *healthy, int* masked)
{
    

    //allocating the array with the necessary values!
    /*(1) N* k2 initially infected person randomly; (2) N* k3 random person who
        will wear face masks every day; (3) N* k4 random person who have been vaccinated; (4)
        for each infected person, whether he / she is quarantined.The N - Person population should
            be updated accordingly.*/


    k2 = (POPULATION * k2) / 100;
    *(infected)= k2;
    k3 = (POPULATION * k3) / 100;
    k4 = (POPULATION * k4) / 100;
    *(vaccinated) = k4;
    k5 = (POPULATION * k5) / 100;
    *(masked) = k5;

    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < k2;i++)
    {
        N[i].days_infected = 0;
        N[i].status = 2;
        int k = rand() % 100;
        if (k > k5)
        {
            N[i].status = 3;
            N[i].days_quarantined = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            N[i].status = 2;
            N[i].days_infected = 0;

        }

    }
    int j;
    for (j = k2;j < (k3)+(k2);j++)
    {
        N[j].mask = 1;

    }
    int k;
    for (k = k3;k < ((k3)+(k4));k++)
    {
        N[k].vaccine = 1;

    }

    return N;
}

void WriteToFile(FILE* OUT, int week)
{
    char str[] = "\n Week";
    fputs(str, OUT);
    putw(week, OUT);
    char str1[] = ",\tHealthy=";
    fputs(str1, OUT);
    putw(healthy, OUT);
    char str2[] = ", \tNew Cases=";
    fputs(str2, OUT);
    putw((infected-oldinfected), OUT);
    char str3[] = ", \tTotal Cases=";
    fputs(str3, OUT);
    putw((infected), OUT);
    
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int days = 0;
    Person A[POPULATION];
    int k2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int k3 = atoi(argv[3]);
    int k4 = atoi(argv[4]);
    int k5 = atoi(argv[5]);
    if ((k2 < 0 && k2>100) || (k3 < 0 && k3>100) || (k4 < 0 && k4>100) || (k5 < 0 && k5>100))
    {
        printf(" \n Please enter k2's, k3's, k4's, k5's value to be between 1 and 100 and try again.");
        return 0;
    }
    FILE* IN = fopen(argv[6], "r");
    FILE* OUT = fopen(argv[7], "w");
    if (IN < 0 || OUT < 0) { perror("\n No such file found!!\n"); exit(1); }
    //reading from the pre-formatted file!!!
    int i, j, k;
    days = 7 * atoi(argv[1]);
    Person *B;
        B= Initialization(IN, A, k2, k3, k4, k5, &vaccinated, &healthy, &infected, &masked);
    for (i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        Simulation(IN, B);
        updation(B);
        // add other necessary parameters for the function call
        // this is the key function that does the simulation
        if (i % 7 == 6) // at the end of each week
        {
            int q = i / 7;
            WriteToFile(OUT,q);
        }
        // write the report to the output file
    }
    // close both input and output files
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Implicit declaration" usually means "you forgot to `#include` the right header file".

Comment: This is a lot of code that's absolutely littered with duplication. You really need to be more comfortable manipulating arrays to reduce how much code you need to write. These variable names are also nearly opaque. What is `hwf`? What is `np`?

Comment: Whatever is going on with `fscanf(++IN, ...)`? This looks extraordinarily out of line. Unless you have an array of `FILE*` handles, which you don't appear to, that's just going to access random memory. Also that `fscanf` call looks really wrong in many other regards. I'd scrap that code entirely and use `fgets()` and `strtok()` and `atof()`.

Comment: Tip: Don't create "throw-away" variables, as in variables that are used once for some trivial thing. If `p_infected` has values that mean something, define a `struct`. Reading into `&p.np` makes a lot more sense than `p_infected[0]` meaning "np", whatever that is. You also define a bunch of throw-away things like `char str[] = ...` and `fputs()` it once. Completely unnecessary and only adds to clutter and confusion. Just `fputs("...", OUT)` and be done with it. Even better: use `fprintf` here!

Comment: What made you think the return code from fopen would be negative on error?

Comment: I don't know. I would just like to know how to solve the issue I asked about.

Comment: MSVC doesn't give me that warning (but it gives *many* others for your code). However, `putw` is not part of the C Standard, so there may be some 'strictness' setting in your project. A possible solution is to replace those calls with `_putw()` (leading underscore), which is a 'standard' POSIX function. I think.

Comment: `putw` is a nonstandard function that's basically a very awkward way to `fwrite()` an object of a particular size.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990423/634919.  Consider rewriting to use `fwrite` instead, or better, a more portable text format.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, this seems to be working.